# React js transferring array value from one component to other

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs. I have created 2 components. 1st component will give me array values from database with ajax call and 2nd component will read the values and print in UI.

In 1st component, I'm getting the value and storing it in setState. now my state has [1,2,3,4], I want to return this array value to other component, how can I return ? Tried many options from google, but my output is not as expected. It's giving me as string format instead of array. This is how I'm returning the array value:

1st component

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.options}
        </div>
    )
}
```

2nd component

```
import Options from './OptionsVaues.jsx';
...
...
const Opts = <Options/>;
...
{Opts}
```

Here the output is as string value as below, but I want it as array value

```
1234
```

Please do let me know what I'm doing wrong here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering an array value, you must first map values of the array to their corresponding element like so:

```
return (
  <div>
    {(this.state.options || []).map(option => (
      <div key={option.id}>
        {option}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

The `key` property is required on array elements. React uses it to determine whether the given array element has been rendered and it's DOM components can be reused. You can learn more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: Hi Marchin, thanx for your reply. I'm getting response as <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>. Instead is it possible to get as array response ?

Comment: @B77, if you want to get a string value that includes all your array elements  you could do {(this.state.options || []).join(', ')}. This would give you `1, 2, 3` for your example.
For more complex arrays though, I recommend the approach described in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Options extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // have an initial state for options in your local state, e.g. this.state = { options: null }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // make xhr request to retrieve options from API
    // store in local state via setState
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.options 
          ? this.state.options.map(option => <Option option={option} />)
          : null
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Option(props) {
  return <div>{props}</div>;
}
```

After you have fetched your data and stored in the local state, you can map over it to render another component that gets the entity from the array. It only maps when there are options in your state, you can read more about the conditional rendering [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react/).